# 8 columns-desktop mode and 1 columns-mobile version

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

i want set bootstrap columns just for mobile view.
forexample in mobile view show rows in 1 column.
(in desktop mode it shows 8 columns without bootstrap)

what class should i use.
i tried col-sm or col-md alone, but didn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please see [ask]. You need to show your attempt. Also tag your Bootstrap version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `8-columns-desktop-mode` need new style apart from bootstrap.
Example: `col-sm-1-8th` and a `@media` for it
([JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Novice_in_dotnet/Lqgn2ury/27/) Expand output tab to left for output).
Because bootstrap has only `col-md-1` to `col-md-12` which can be equally split into either 12 `col-md-1`s or 6 `col-md-2`s or 5 `col-md-2`s or 4 `col-md-3`s or 3 `col-md-4`s or 2 `col-md-6`s or 1 `col-md-12`s. Whereas  8 equal parts requires 8 `100/8`s

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-md-1-8th {
    flex: 0 0 12.5%;
    max-width: 12.5%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  .col-md-1-8th {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

.col-md-1-8th {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  .col-sm-12-custom {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12-custom col-md-1-8th">1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12-custom col-md-1-8th">2</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12-custom col-md-1-8th">3</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12-custom col-md-1-8th">4</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12-custom col-md-1-8th">5</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12-custom col-md-1-8th">6</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12-custom col-md-1-8th">7</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12-custom col-md-1-8th">8</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12-custom col-md-1-8th">9</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12-custom col-md-1-8th">10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Red Always welcome mate :)

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is mobile-first framework, so you always work from mobile upwards.

Not exactly sure what you want to achieve. But if you only use the `col-lg-4` class on your columns, it will result in 1 column on mobile and 3 columns on lg breakpoint & above.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4">...</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">...</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">...</div>
</div>
```

If you really want to do it just for mobile it would require CSS/SASS. Something like below should work, but it is kind of fighting against the BS convention:

```
.custom-column-class {
  @include media-breakpoint-down(sm) {
    @include make-col-ready();
    @include make-col(4);
  }
}
```

Comment: Tahnk's it worked somehow too.